# How to evaluate environment variables into a string in Python?

Tags: python, filesystems, environment-variables

I have a string representing a path.  Because this application is used on Windows, OSX and Linux, we've defined environment variables to properly map volumes from the different file systems.  The result is:

```
"$C/test/testing"
```

What I want to do is evaluate the environment variables in the string so that they're replaced by their respective volume names.  Is there a specific command I'm missing, or do I have to take `os.environ.keys()` and manually replace the strings?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use [os.path.expandvars](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) to expand the environment variables in the string, for example:

```
>>> os.path.expandvars('$C/test/testing')
'/stackoverflow/test/testing'
```

Comment: Its a pity there's no way to escape a $ to stop some variables being expanded. For example,  $C/test/$$ACTION or $C/test/\$ACTION to produce the string '/stackoverflow/test/$ACTION

Comment: @JulianMann If you define `DOLLARSIGN` as a variable, you can use `${DOLLARSIGN}` where you want to use a literal dollar sign.

Comment: Note that this will not expand variables that are not set. If you want them to expand into empty values (like Bash does), you may want to use `string.Template` instead.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 3 you can do:

```
'{VAR}'.format(**os.environ))
```

for example

```
>>> 'hello from {PWD}'.format(**os.environ))
hello from /Users/william
```

Comment: Great idea! No need to create variables like DOLLAR='$'. Thanks.

Comment: For clarification, `'{VAR1} and {VAR2}'.format(**os.environ)` passes the list of variables present in the string to `os.environ`, which is passed to the `_Environ` constructor, and the double asterisk unpacks the values returned via the `__getitem__` indexer, which effectively performs`os.environ["VAR"]` for each variable.

I had to search through a bunch of documentation to understand why this worked. I could be slightly wrong on some of this, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 4):

The `os.path.expandvars` solution will not expand variables that aren't set.

If you want unset variables to be expanded to empty values (like the shell does), you can use [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings), example:

```
import os
from string import Template
from collections import defaultdict

def expand_posix_vars(posix_expr, context):
    env = defaultdict(lambda: '')
    env.update(context)
    return Template(posix_expr).substitute(env)

conf_str = "${PREFIX}something"

assert "something" == expand_posix_vars(conf_str, {})
assert "hellosomething" == expand_posix_vars(conf_str, {"PREFIX": "hello"})
```